# Transforming circle in z - plane to w - plane

Tags: complex-numbers, transformation

A circle in z - plane with diameter $AB, A=(a,0), B=(b,0)$ is transformed to w - plane by transformation $w=\frac{1}{z}$. We need to find the locus of $w$

Answer (score 0):

$A$ and $B$ in z - plane are transformed to $\left(\frac{1}{a},0\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{b},0\right)$ in w - plane respectively. Everywhere on the circle except at $A$ and $B$ we have

$$
Re\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)=0\rightarrow Re\left(\frac{w-\frac{1}{a}}{w-\frac{1}{b}}\right)=0
$$

Therefore the circle is transformed to a circle in w - plane with diameter $CD, C=\left(\frac{1}{a},0\right), D=\left(\frac{1}{b},0\right)$

Comment: @JeanMarie there is an option to make this a sharing, Q&A style. i ticked that option, but do not know if i have to do anything else

Comment: I have deleted various comments here. I'll also note that there is nothing wrong with answering your own question.